# WKWebView catch HTTP error codes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, wkwebview

When i return any http error from my page (currently 401, but i tried also with 404 and so on)

http://min60.com/__personal/e401.php

the delegate callbacks of the WKWebView don't return an error

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailProvisionalNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error {
```

How to catch such errors?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The key was to wait for the response and then inspect the object, no error is called on http code

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler {

    if ([navigationResponse.response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse * response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)navigationResponse.response;
        if (response.statusCode == 401) {

            // here we go

        }

    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicyAllow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
public func webView(
    _ webView: WKWebView,
    decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,
    decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void
) {
    if
        let httpResponse = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        !(200..<400).contains(httpResponse.statusCode)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```