# Use shared WKWebViewCookies for a request

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have a few different WKWebViews inside my project they are all sharing cookies over a single WKProcessPool.

Now I want to make a request on a REST API and need to send exactly that cookies from that WKWebViews to that API. Is there a way to get the cookies? Everything I get are the cookies from the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` but they seem not really in sync with the cookies I use in the WKWebView. Or is there even the possibility to make a request that uses the WKProcessPool too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If your cookies are not HTTP-only, you can get them by evaluating JavaScript command `document.cookie` on `webView` and use them for your request.
If they are HTTP-only, it seems that there is no working method to do this.
There is no documented way to sync cookies between `WKWebView` and `NSURLSession` as far as I know.

2) Another approach (if cookies belong to same domain which REST API belongs) - create "background" `webView` with same process pool and perform all operations to REST API via this instance - cookies will be added automatically (even HTTP-only):

1. You can set any params (method/body/headers/etc) to request and load
   it via `loadRequest:`; If your REST API returns JSON, you can use JavaScript command
   `document.body` to get it;
2. Getting response code a little bit harder - you need to implement
   `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:` method of
   `WKNavigationDelegate` and [catch
   it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32936297/1044073).
3. Also, you need to keep in mind that you can perform only 1 request
   in `webView` simultaneously. So, you may need to create some queue
   of requests that will be performed one after another.