# WKWebView catch HTTP error codes with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

this question is identical to the following: [WKWebView catch HTTP error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936168/wkwebview-catch-http-error-codes); unfortunately the methods in Obj-C are not applicable to Swift 4, thus the cited `WKNavigationResponse.response` is no longer of type `NSHTTPURLResponse` so it doesn't have the http status code.

But the issue is still the same: I need to get the http status code of the answer to detect if the expected page is loaded or not.

Please note that `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error)` delegate is not called in case of `404` but only in case of network issue (i.e. server offline); the `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` is called instead.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Using a `WKNavigationDelegate` on the `WKWebView` you can get the status code from the response each time one is received.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,
             decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

    if let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        if response.statusCode == 401 {
            // ...
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`HTTPURLResponse` is a subclass of `URLResponse`. The Swift way of “conditional downcasting” is the conditional cast `as?`, this can be combined with conditional binding `if let`:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,
             decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

    if let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        if response.statusCode == 401 {
            // ...
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```